# Can't recognize if it's accessed from desktop or mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mobile, view

I am trying to create views for mobile devices. I found someone else's code, and this is in `ApplicationController`:

```
def check_for_mobile
  session[:mobile_override] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
  prepare_for_mobile if mobile_device?
end
def prepare_for_mobile
  prepend_view_path Rails.root + 'app' + 'views_mobile'
end
def mobile_device?
  if session[:mobile_override]
    session[:mobile_override] == "1"
    session[:is_mobile] = nil
  else
    (request.user_agent =~ /(iPhone|iPod|Android|webOS|Mobile|iPad)/)
    session[:is_mobile] = true
  end
end
helper_method :mobile_device?
```

The code doesn't distinguish between desktop and mobile properly. When I run this code, views are generated for mobile even if I use the application on laptop. Why is that?

I don't understand the definition of method `check_for_mobile`. Where does the `params[:mobile]` come from?

Comment: For Rails 4 you should use variants, the build in support for mobile views. Details here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-variants

Comment: Cristian, thanks for this, I followed this approach and it works like a charm! Please feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I added variants as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`params[:mobile]` is set in the URL.  Odds are there is a link in the header/footer of the site with the current url and `?mobile=1` appended. The above code would see that and switch to the mobile view regardless of the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4.1 introduced a new concept, [variants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-variants), which lets you to build views for each kind of device.

```
# The request variant is a specialization of the request format,
# like :tablet, :phone, or :desktop.
# Example from Rails upgrade Guide:

before_filter do
  request.variant = :tablet if request.user_agent =~ /iPad/
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html do |html|
    html.tablet # renders app/views/projects/show.html+tablet.erb
    html.phone { extra_setup; render ... }
  end
end
```